# Run Tomcat app like eclipse but without eclipse

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, build, automation

My team basically uses Eclipse religiously, however contractors and freelancers tend to have different preferences for IDEs and workflows. The issue is running our Spring/Maven/Tomcat app without eclipse (or any other IDE) in a user friendly manner. I'm thinking there has to be a quick console command like "mvn run" or a simple .sh and .bat file.

With Eclipse you can:

- right click project -> run as -> run on server

Nicest part, eclipse will scan your project and refresh resources as you type without even restarting Tomcat. Also Eclipse will run the project from the workspace without moving anything to Tomcat or needing to make the WAR. The option says, "Use workspace metadata (does not modify Tomcat installation)"

[Here the settings in eclipse for my Tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXzLo.png)

However, without eclipse, all I know what to tell them is run "mvn install" then copy/paste the war file to Tomcats "webapps" directory. This process is quite tedious and I usually convince them to use eclipse and they give me a frowny face.

So our build stack is like so: Maven, ANT, NPM, Grunt. Is there any magic with any of these four to run the project on an external Tomcat easily? I'm really wanting to hear some stories of others in the same situation and some guidance where to look.

All I found online was the following: https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-reload. I can't quite tell if this is even what I'm looking for though.

To note, we are using a standalone Tomcat v9 because maven-tomcat is only v7.

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to modify your build scripts.

Just create a context.xml file in Tomcat that points directly to your .war file, and make to "reloadable".

Example: In `$TOMCAT_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost` create a file with the context name you want, e.g. `MyApp.xml`. That will make `localhost:8080/MyApp` be the URL to your app (or whatever port it's listening on).

File content should be:

```xml
<Context docBase="C:/path/to/MyApp.war" reloadable="true" />
```

Without the `C:` prefix if you're not on Windows, of course.

Now, whenever you update the .war file, e.g. using `mvn install`, Tomcat will automatically reload the app (slight delay, up to 20 seconds I believe).

Comment: Now that's what I'm talking about. This gives me an idea. I can use ANT to set a "MYAPP_HOME" and make sure devs have "CATALINA_HOME" already set. Then I can just copy your snippet file to where it needs to go in tomcat.

`<Context docBase="%MYAPP_HOME%/path/to/war" reloadable="true" />`

Answer (score 1):

> To note, we are using a standalone Tomcat v9 because maven-tomcat is
>   only v7.

I don't understand that sentence.

You can use maven cargo or maven tomcat plugin to deploy to tomcat.

For tomcat plugin, look at this :
http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/
I don't know if it works with Tomcat 9 but with tomcat 8, it works perfectly.
Have you tried that plugin?

For cargo, look at this :
https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Deploying+to+a+running+container.html

In both case, the idea is configuring the plugin in your pom.xml where you package your war in order to trigger the deploy with the suitable phase of the lifecycle (a phase is bound by default but you can change it).

For example, here an example with Tomcat Maven plugin where I tell Tomcat plugin to deploy, during the pre-integration-test phase, the artifact produced by the underlying pom.xml  :

```
<project>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <configuration>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/mymanager</url>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>tomcat-deploy</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

For detailed information, feel free to read official documentations.

Comment: Really helpful thank you, but too much for now. Later on I'm definitely going to try out the CodeHaus Cargo. It seems to be a happy medium between embedding Tomcat vs Standalone. 

This way my project could install Tomcat for you and Cargo adds all kinds of fun magic. 

This part:

_To note, we are using a standalone Tomcat v9 because maven-tomcat is only v7._

I was simply referring to the tomcat7-maven-plugin you mentioned is v7 instead of Tomcat v9. I'm just trying to stay as up to date as possible.